# Why does the species of Gemma's bird change?

Tags: sons-of-anarchy

In numerous early episodes of Sons of Anarchy, Gemma Teller is shown to own a cockatoo (an umbrella, IIRC).

In at least one episode (in either season 4 or 5), the same cage is suddenly occupied by a cockatiel. The cockatoo is never seen again.

At the end of season 6, the cage is now occupied by a crow. There are no signs of either the cockatoo or the cockatiel.

Thematically, one could argue that the species and color change tracks Gemma's progression (white -> gray -> black). But is there any official explanation to the the change in birds?

Comment: More than likely it was a reference to Clay's progression in the sotryline/Gemma's life

Comment: I didn't catch this last year...I disagree as Clay was never ever a "White Knight" ... But Gemma was good to Jax, and at least originally to his wife as well. Then she started going bad, in little bits, until finally, at the end, unredeamably so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this](http://www.examiner.com/article/sons-of-anarchy-spoilers-kurt-sutter-says-more-a-less-guns) article, Kurt Sutter is said to say:

> While Kurt would love to keep the pit bull that Tig rescued as a club mascot, he says that the dog's day rate is a little too far out of the budget. Also, Sutter says that Gemma's birds have become a running gag and she has a new one every couple episodes. There will likely not be a return of any bird in particular.

Answer (score 1):

I know there was an explanation of the change between the Cockatoo and the cockatiel either in the episode "Family Recipe" or in the deleted scenes. Tig asks Gemma what happened to the bird. She said he had a heart attack. There is no explanation of what happened to her cockatiel "Clay".

Comment: I'm guessing the deleted scenes, as the transcript of the show available here: http://foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=7290 (Horrible formatting alert!) for that episode makes no mention of the bird.

Answer (score -3):

I watch *SOA* about once a year (waiting for good shows to start). I think the bird transition represents Jax's transition.

It was white when he wanted to follow John's idealism and get the club out of guns; it was grey while he's in the cartel/Pope fiasco, and he wants to get the club out of the crap, but he has to get dirty... a grey area. It was black when he was fully in evil mode, avenging Tara against the "Chinese" then his own mom.